# Updating from Rails 4.0 to 4.1 gives sass-rails railties version conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to update my Rails 4.0 app to 4.1. The app uses `sass-rails`, and when I try to update it using `bundle update rails` I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.1.0) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 4.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.1.1)
```

Any idea how to work around it or fix it?

Comment: probably, you define sass version in `gemfile`, if it so - remove it.

Comment: I do, as version `~> 4.0`, but the latest version is `4.0.3`. Removing the version identifier doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Rails 4.1.0 or 4.1.1?  4.1.1 depends on railties 4.1.1 which seems to match what sass-rails wants.

Comment: remove and `bundle update`?

Comment: Or try to install `4.1.1` version.

Comment: Just updated to `rails 4.1.1` and that seemed to pass. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, update to:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of sass rails solves this issue:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
```

Comment: All the other solutions didn't fix the issue for me; this one did.

Answer (score 0):

Updating bundler solved this for me:

```
gem install bundler
```

Apparently there was a bug in older bundlers.

Taken from related question: [sass-rails requires sprockets 2.0.0 but rails 4.1.0 requires sprockets 2.12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107565/sass-rails-requires-sprockets-2-0-0-but-rails-4-1-0-requires-sprockets-2-12-1)

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 1h trying to add susy 2 to my project... Thamn are those dependencies a bi*ch... To set up rails 4, sass-rails, compass-rails and susy I changed my Gemfile into:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'susy'
```

What I didn't want to do, but ended up doing is updating *rails* from `4.0.3` to `4.1.1` and what bothers me even more is using `sass-rails 5.0.0.beta1`