# sass-rails requires sprockets 2.0.0 but rails 4.1.0 requires sprockets 2.12.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I'm trying to upgrade my application from `rails 3.2.16` to `rails 4.1.0`, I get into troubles right at the beginning when I try to call the bundler:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) ruby depends on
        sprockets (2.12.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (2.1.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.1.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.1.0)
```

and (part) of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem "rake"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem 'sass-rails'
```

Comment: Which version of Bundler are you using? Have you tried updating to the latest version? (Just run `gem install bundler` to update.)

Comment: well spotted, updating bundle made the trick.. .

Comment: Good to hear. I'll rewrite this as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some older versions of Bundler have a bug that can cause this failure to resolve. Updating to the latest version might help.

Run this to update:

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I spent countless hours looking for this before this question existed.

Comment: after updating bundler (thanks for that hint, Tim!), I had to run `bundle update` instead of `bundle install`.

Comment: this answer (running `gem install bundler` then `bundle update` didn't work for me). I'm still getting "compatible version" problems with sprockets and "actionpack". When I ran `gem install bundler` it did update.